# Question on Lagrange theorem

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

Find  order of $H$ if $H$ is subgroup  of some group of order $100$ and $H$ contains no element of order $2$, with $H$ non cyclic

The ans given in a book is $25$.
 I can understand that $\operatorname{O(H)}$ divides $\operatorname{O(G)}$

I couldn't understand the below point:
since $H$ is non-cyclic, therefore $\operatorname{O(H)}$ is not equal to $1,2$ and $5$ so the possibilites for $\operatorname{O(H)}$ are $4,10,20,25,50 \text{ and } 100$
Now ,groups of even order must contain an element of order $2$
since $H$ does not ,it must have odd order
thus $\operatorname{O(H)} =25$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct.  The existence of an element of order $2$ would follow from Cauchy's theorem, in case $H$ had even order.  That enables you to close it out.

Note that, essentially by Lagrange, groups of prime order are cyclic.

Comment: Dear Chris ,can you help me out to understand "since H is non-cyclic, therefore O(H) is not equal to 1,2 and 5 so the possibilites for O(H) are 4,10,20,25,50 and 100

Comment: $2$ and $5$ are prime.  As I mentioned, groups of prime order are cyclic.  To be cyclic means there's an element whose order equals the order of the group.  But by Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element divides the order of the group.  But primes don't have any divisors, other than themselves and one.  Finally, of course the trivial group, $\{e\}$ is cyclic.

Comment: Thank You Sir , for your clarification about my queries.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Solution seems to be ok. $H$ cannot be of prime order since  **Group of prime order is cyclic**.  Also note that  **If G is a group of even order then number of elements of order two is odd(exercise)** . Given order of group is  $100$. Divisors are possibilities for subgroup not exactly subgroup. If order of $H$ is even note that  **Cauchy's theorem states that if $G$ is a finite group and $p$ is a prime number dividing the order of $G$ (the number of elements in $G$), then $G$ contains an element of order $p$** . So the only possible order of $H$ is $25$ which divides $100$

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.